# Creating C++ project from existing code in VS2005 or VS2010

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

Could someone please be kind enough to provide details of how one would go about creating a VS c++ project from an existing codebase?

In my scenario I am attempting to use the following code http://gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/. I have downloaded the entire trunk to a folder on my computer but now wish to open it in the VS IDE. I have both VS 2010 and VS2005.

Do I simply have to create a new "empty c++ project" and manually add all the files? Or is there some other way?

How do I make sure that the required dependencies and the provided makefile is correctly added to the project?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very difficulty to add a new Windows solution for your project. Whether it compiles or not is hard to say, as the project might invoke some unix-specific header files, for example .

Anyway, you need to create a new solution. Then add all source files to your project. You don't have to mimic the existing folder structure. I would suggest you try to compile all source files, if something is not compiling, check the Makefile. Sometimes, a file is included in the revision but actually not compiled.

It's hard to guide you specifically, come back and make a new question if you have any problem in compiling or linking.

Comment: Thank you... Thats good enough to confirm I am at least on the right track.